# Change port of IIS management service on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, iis

So, how to do it? Apparently in client SKUs the management service properties are not available in IIS Manager. I read that it might be possible to do it via Powershell but haven't found how to do it...

Comment: What version of IIS are you running?

Comment: it's windows 7 so IIS 7.5